# background-color of jquery datepicker is overwritten

Tags: jquery, html, css, datepicker

I'm trying to change the background color of jquery datepicker component. I already put the css on my css file, but the setted values is overwritten.

I've put the code bellow on my css file:

```
.ui-datepicker-week-end a  {    
background-image: none;
background-color: #EFE584;
 }
```

Take a look at code: http://jsfiddle.net/dvjWk/

Answer (score 2):

A quick check using firebug reveals that anchor element has the class '.ui-state-default' assigned hence the styles are overwritten by .ui-state-default as this is more specific.

Make the css selector more specific by

```
.ui-datepicker-week-end a.ui-state-default  {    
 background-image: none;
 background-color: #EFE584;
}
```

Comment: Also reference your css file AFTER the jquery-UI one since if the specificities are the same, the last one registered will be applied.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to customize the appearance of JQuery-UI elements is by downloading a customized version based on your needs:

http://jqueryui.com/download

See the "Theme" configuration on the right side.